# Verify if ∑(+d-√) is convergent or divergent II

Tags: calculus

I was curious about the following series $$\sum _{j=1}^{\infty } \left(\sqrt{d+j}-\sqrt{j}\right)$$ where d is a interger positive, in principle applying several convergence tests the series is clearly divergent, but it is summable by analytical continuation of the zeta function and the like the trick is to remove the divergent term and then add it
take $$\sqrt{d+j}-\sqrt{j}=\frac{1}{16} d^3 \left(\frac{1}{j}\right)^{5/2}-\frac{1}{8} d^2 \left(\frac{1}{j}\right)^{3/2}+\frac{1}{2} d \sqrt{\frac{1}{j}}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{j}\right)^{7/2}\right)$$ and rest the divergent term
$$\sum _{j=1}^{\infty } \left(\left(\sqrt{d+j}-\sqrt{j}\right)-\frac{1}{2} d 
\sqrt{\frac{1}{j}}\right)$$ and sum each term as zeta function to get the result
$$\zeta \left(-\frac{1}{2},d+1\right)-\frac{d \zeta \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}{2}-\zeta \left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)$$
as and example d=1 you get the result$$-\frac{\zeta \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}{2}-1$$ sum the $$\frac{\zeta \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}{2}$$ and get the result -1
I don't know if this result or way of proceeding is correct but it seems to work, do you know of any method?? to directly obtain a numerical result a priori I have tried euler maclaurin and other but they don't work

Comment: @geetha290krm The OP already stated that the series is divergent. The OP is asking about other summability methods, see [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergent_series)

Answer (score 1):

Consider the partial sum
$$S_p=\sum _{j=1}^{p} \left(\sqrt{d+j}-\sqrt{j}\right)$$

There are several ways to write it; for example
$$S_p=-\zeta \left(-\frac{1}{2},d+p+1\right)+\zeta
   \left(-\frac{1}{2},d+1\right)-H_p^{\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)}$$ where appear generalized harmonic numbers and  the Hurwitz zeta function.

Now, expand as series for large $p$

$$S_p=H_{d+p}^{\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)}+\left(-\frac{2
   p^{3/2}}{3}-\frac{p^{1/2}}{2}+\left(\zeta \left(-\frac{1}{2},d+1\right)-2 \zeta
   \left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)-\frac{1}{24p^{1/2}}+O\left(
   \frac{1}{p^{5/2}}\right)\right)$$ Working the first term, use
$$H_{q}^{\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)}=\frac{2 q^{3/2}}{3}+\frac{q^{1/2}}{2}+\zeta
   \left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)+\frac{1}{24q^{1/2}}+O\left(\frac{1}{q^{5/2}}\right)$$ Replace $q$ by $d+p$ and continue with Taylor series to make
$$H_{d+p}^{\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)}=\frac{2 p^{3/2}}{3}+\left(d+\frac{1}{2}\right) \sqrt{p}-\frac{\zeta
   \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)}{4 \pi }+\frac{6 d^2+6 d+1}{24p^{1/2}} 
   -\frac{2 d^3+3 d^2+d}{48 p^{3/2}}   +O\left(\frac{1}{p^{5/2}}\right)$$ Finally
$$S_p=d \sqrt p+\left(\zeta \left(-\frac{1}{2},d+1\right)+\frac{\zeta
   \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)}{4 \pi }\right)+\frac{d(d+1)}{4p^{1/2}}-\frac{d (d+1) (2 d+1)}{48 p^{3/2}}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^{5/2}}\right)$$

Trying for $p=10^4$ and a few values of $d$, some results
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
d & \text{approximation} & \text{exact} \\
 1 & 99.0049998750000 & 99.0049998750062 \\
 2 & 197.600785812627 & 197.600785812683 \\
 3 & 295.883733880058 & 295.883733880283 \\
 4 & 393.903731880058 & 393.903731880683 \\
 5 & 491.692660777558 & 491.692660778964 \\
 6 & 589.273166534775 & 589.273166537530 \\
 7 & 686.662409098710 & 686.662409103609 \\
 8 & 783.873973973964 & 783.873973982061 \\
 9 & 880.918963848964 & 880.918963861615 \\
 10 & 977.806673688796 & 977.806673707692
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: In the result (−1)=−1/12, the left-hand side should not be interpreted as $$\underset{N\to \infty }{\text{lim}}\left(\sum _{j=i}^N j\right)$$, because that's not what it is, the correct way to do this is often mathematically simple, such as analytic continuation